# MongoDB: IDs in url like MySql, How?

Tags: mysql, mongodb

Normally, when I have to open a detailed page of an Element in sql, I create links like this one:

```
http://www.mrwhite.it/posts/1/
```

How do I achieve this result with MongoDB? It uses ids very long, so I assume that I don't have to use it, right?

Comment: Note that URIs *very rarely* are impacted by the underlying db(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use that string Id of mingodb  too but if you don't want that, then goto the below link and know how you can generate long type of id like MySQL.
[MongoDB-AutoIncrement Id](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/)